How to limit access to setter?
simplified:
public interface ISomeInterface
{
  int Value { get; }
}

I have like 100 function overrides that consume Value through an ISomeInterface parameter
Now in one particular case I need to modify Value. But if I add a setter to the interface all overrides can set the value.
Can I limit the setter to one particular class, maybe using an attribute?
There must be a better solution than to add comment to tell other contributors not to use the setter.

How about declaring another interface that inherits from this one? Put the setter in that new interface. The function that needs the setter would access the setter through the new interface.

Just use concrete implementation in this particular case?

@Sweeper the interface is a parameter to the overridden function. sorry if that wasn't clear. How would I have that one function use another interface if all have the same parameter list?

Why don't you add a method to the class that needs to be able to set the attribute, instead of adding a setter to the interface?

The interface defines what you can and can't do to properties - if you want different behavior you need a different interface, or add that capability to the class itself. Clients using the "read only" interface won't be able to set the property without casting to some other interface or the class directly.

Can you provide some more context with an example of how you're trying to use it? For example, if you are only setting the value once (e.g. on initialisation) then a Builder pattern might help. I'm not saying that's the answer; rather I'm just illustrating that we could offer alternatives once we know more about what you're trying to solve. Thanks.

Messing around with access levels on properties where part of it is specified on the interface gets painful fast. You could spend time experimenting with protected set or internal set, but I don't think you can get anywhere useful.
You could do this, however:
public interface ISomeInterface
{
  int Value { get; }
}

internal interface ISomeInterfaceWithSetMethods : ISomeInterface
{
    void SetValue(int value);
}

Then you can separately define classes that must have the set available and those that must not have it, by implementing ISomeInterfaceWithSetMethods or ISomeInterface, respectively. Both types of classes will all look like ISomeInterface.
Another option: if you still want to allow multiple implementations from the same base type, you could consider an abstract class instead:
public abstract class SomeBase
{
    public abstract int Value { get; }

    internal abstract void SetValue(int value);
}

Feel free to comment for feedback.

try this:
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public interface ISomeInterfaceWithSetter : ISomeInterface
{
    new int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public int Value { get; }
}

public class SomeClassWithSetter : ISomeInterfaceWithSetter
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

And in your method you would have parameter of type ISomeInterface, which you can try to cast to ISomeInterfaceWithSetter with is or as oeprators. I hope I understood your problem correctly.
